# Answer is wrong when i include sort() function (Rudolf and the ticket from codeforces)

Tags: c++

so i was wondering why my code somehow gives the correct output only when i remove the 2 sort functions as the value themselves don't change?

[The question](https://codeforces.com/contest/1941/problem/A)

Also, I'm unable to post on code forces yet as I'm a beginner so i thought i could get help here. Thanks so much in advance!

My code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    
    while(t--){
        int n, m, k, count = 0;
        cin >> n >> m >> k;
        int A[1000], B[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            cin >> A[i];
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
            cin >> B[i];
        }
        sort(begin(A), end(A));
        sort(begin(B), end(B));
        
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
                if(A[i] + B[j] <= k){
                    count++;
                }
                
            }
        }
        cout << count << endl;
    }
}
```

Can't figure out why it will only work when i remove sort function

Comment: The problem is that you are sorting all 1000 of the elements in your arrays, not the first `n` and `m` respectively, Try `sort(A, A+n); sort(B, B+m);` to only sort the parts of the arrays that actually have values. Better still use vectors not arrays.

Comment: The basic problem here is that arrays don't have a dynamic size. There is no way that `end(A)` is going to know that you have only added `n` numbers to your array, it's just going to give you the whole array, which is all 1000 numbers. This is one reason why you should be using vectors not arrays. There are many others.

Comment: How much time did you spent learning C++ before you started competitve coding? You should really learn the C++ basics first (things like std::vector etc), passing by const/reference etc. C++ is not a language you will learn by trial and error, even getting green check_marks for your assignment tells you nothing about the quality of your C++ code. So my advice stay away from competitive coding for a long time

Comment: Learn C++ from : [a recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or from [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) that site is decent and pretty up to date.
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) for reference material (and examples). When you have done all that keep referring to the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with the latest best practices since C++ keeps evolving.n

Comment: Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: @PepijnKramer thanks for the advice, but i thought that practice will help with getting more familiar with c++. I didn't want to only read and not practice as that's what i did for a while and felt like i was going nowhere :/

Comment: You will indeed get nowhere with only reading. But the other way around is also true. Usually my approach is to at least scan through material (to get a lay of the land). Then take a practical problem and look back at some of the material I scanned previously that may apply. For example take cppreference's containers and algorithms sections. Scan for what is in there read what each class can do (but don't go over all the methods). then try to use some of that in an exercise... the first goal should not be to pass all the tests but to use stuff from C++ and its standard library.

Comment: For example you read the first few lines of [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  And you will see *1) std::vector is a sequence container that encapsulates dynamic size arrays* that's all you need to know for now. Now you have a problem with an array you don't know the size of... and you can think back and think... hey there was a class for that. Maybe you have to look for it again, but you also know you don't have to invent stuff yourself.

Comment: Will look into trying that out, much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sort(begin(A), end(A));` sorts the **all 1000 elements** of the array `int A[1000];`. This includes uninitialized elements, so the sorting may put garbage values to what is processed and may lead to wrong output.

Removing the sorting eliminates this garbage putting and make the output correct.

Comment: Removing the sorting makes the output correct IF the input data is presorted.

Comment: And thats' why a "C" style arrays should be a thing of the past and std::vector should be used (when you only know the array size at runtime).

Comment: Oh my god thanks so much haha i didn't think about the garbage values. Thanks!!!!